# Pool workers do not complete all tasks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a relatively simple python multiprocessing script that sets up a pool of workers that append output to a pandas `dataframe` by way of a custom manager. What I am finding is when I call close()/join() on the pool, not all the tasks submitted by apply_async are being completed.

Here's a simplified example that submits 1000 jobs but only half complete causing an assertion error. Have I overlooked something very simple or is this perhaps a bug?

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, Pool

class DataFrameResults:
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = DataFrame(columns=("A", "B")) 

    def get_count(self):
        return self.results["A"].count()

    def register_result(self, a, b):
        self.results = self.results.append([{"A": a, "B": b}], ignore_index=True)

class MyManager(BaseManager): pass

MyManager.register('DataFrameResults', DataFrameResults)

def f1(results, a, b):
    results.register_result(a, b)

def main():
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    results = manager.DataFrameResults()

    pool = Pool(processes=4)

    for (i) in range(0, 1000):
        pool.apply_async(f1, [results, i, i*i])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print results.get_count()
    assert results.get_count() == 1000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[EDIT]** The issue which you're seeing is because of this code:

```
self.results = self.results.append(...)
```

this isn't atomic. So in some cases, the thread will be interrupted after reading `self.results` (or while appending) but before it can assign the new frame to `self.results` -> this instance will be lost.

The correct solution is to wait use the results objects to get the results and then append all of them in the main thread.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't appear to help. I collect all the pool results as suggested but they still terminate half-way through. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How do you know they "terminate half-way through"? Did you count how many results were returned?

Comment: The assertion checks whether the number of results entered into the dataframe is 1000 (number of callbacks). When I run the script the number of records in dataframe usually comes back at 495 to 510. A different result each time.

Comment: Interestingly, if I switch from a DataFrame to a list it works perfectly. So could be a pandas DataFrame/multiprocessing issue. Although I can't see how as I would expect the custom manager to sandbox the DataFrame and communicte via pipes.

Comment: It's because of the assignment in `register_result()`. See my edits.

Comment: That sounds more like it. I've added a Lock around that statement and seems to work. Thanks again :-)

Comment: this is wrong: "The threads will exit but not all jobs will have been processed." You could add logging to see that all jobs are complete after `pool.join()`. The only issue was that `register_results()` is not thread-safe. As @bsdz said it could be solved by synchronizing access e.g., via Lock.